# Does the Pale Stranger's Pistols ability suppress the effects of unusual pistols?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, firearms

Does the [Pale Stranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/pale-stranger/?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)'s Pistols supernatural ability suppress the the magic of a magic pistol such as a [*pistol of the infinite sky*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/pistol-of-the-infinite-sky/) such that it functions as a mere +1 pistol while wielded? What about non-magical yet unusual pistols like the zero pistol or a dragon pistol?  Do these instead use the normal 'pistol' stats for the weapon of the same name (that is, the stats for a *+1 pistol*) or should this be read as using the weapon classification 'pistol' instead (that is, like a *+1* pistol)? Lastly, what about ammunition used with the weapon?  If a dragon pistol is loaded with unusual ammunition like a Salt Shot, can the weapon be fired by the Stranger at all (since the ammunition can only be used with the cone-firing option)?  Would a pitted bullet still deliver its poisonous cargo, since the ammunition's ability is entirely separate from the weapon it is fired from? Basically, what parts of an unusual pistol-category weapon does the Pistols ability replace?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the ability in question reads

> any pistol a pale stranger wields functions as a +1 pistol.

I believe the intention is that the creature is not reliant on its own weapons - any similar weapons it picks up become enchanted, and reload themselves. However, RAW, yes, it would also overwrite any better enchantments with just a +1. Nothing in the ability appears to change the basic definition of the weapon itself, so I would expect unusual types of pistol to stay so - a dragon pistol or laser pistol or even a double-barreled pistol would still be just that, but would gain a +1 enchantment, even if that was relatively meaningless for that type of weapon or ammo loaded.

For the other situations you outline, the vast majority of them would fall under GM interpretation. For myself, I would likely rule that any ammunition already in the weapon would fire as it normally would, but once fired, would be replaced by a standard round.